# Posting variable returns invalid

Tags: php, mysql, validation, post

I am using a simple PHP script for the activation  part of one of my applications. The applications posts one variable to the page (`http://validate.zbrowntechnology.info/WebLock.php?method=validate`). The variable is the serial number, posted as '*Serial*'. Each time I post to this page, it returns Invalid. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$serial = $_POST['Serial'];
$method = $_GET['method'];

$con = mysql_connect("HOSTHERE", "USERHERE", "PASSHERE");
if(!$con) {
  die('Unable to connect to MySQL:  ' . mysql_error());
}


if($method == "validate") {

  mysql_select_db("zach_WebLock", $con);

  $query = "SELECT Key, Status FROM Validation WHERE Key='".mysql_real_escape_string($serial)."'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "Valid";
  } else {
    echo "Invalid";
  }
} else {
  echo "Unkown Method";
}
?>
```

Here Is The Error From PHP,

> PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Try adding an else statement.. if($method == 'validate') { // code here } else { echo 'No method'; }

Comment: Before asking what's wrong with the script, you should try issuing the query directly in MySQL. "SELECT Key, Status FROM Validation WHERE key = '123'" or whatever you think the value of serial is.

Comment: @mellowsoon, tried that and it returned properly.

Comment: I just saw your update. mysql_query is returning false, which means your query is wrong. Try using mysql_error() to get the reason why.

Comment: Yes, and it returned the proper value of 2772.

Comment: This is how the DB is setup: Table: Validation    Key is VARCHAR(50) and the value of Key is _2772_.

Comment: Yes, but have you tried the mysql_error() function, which has been mentioned a couple times now? The error you're getting regarding a boolean means mysql_query() is returning false. That means there's an error in your query. mysql_error() will tell you exactly what the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after the query use mysql_error() to see what happened. And Key is a bad choice for a column name because it's a reserved word in SQL. You can enclose it in `` to tell MySQL it's an identifier. Do some more debugging like this:

```
...
if (!mysql_select_db("zach_WebLock", $con)) die('mysql_select_db failed');

$query = "SELECT `Key`, Status FROM Validation WHERE `Key`='".mysql_real_escape_string($serial)."'";
print "query=$query<br>\n";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
print "error=" . mysql_error($con);
...
```

Comment: The Key column name? I hate when that happens. I took over a database recently that has a column named `date` in several tables.

Comment: To be fair, some other people below told you to do the same thing 30 minutes ago ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on this line:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 {
```

Is that missing in your code or just your question?

You may also want to add

```
if (!$result) {
    print mysql_error();
}
```

after your query

Comment: No, now it just returns _Invalid_, no matter what I POST.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you pass `$con` to mysql_query?

Comment: @bemace, it still returns _Invalid_.

Comment: Did you try adding the `if (!$result)` check too?

Comment: @bemace, yes.. it still returned _Invalid_. I looked through the server logs and found the error from PHP. I appended it to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This 
`$query = "SELECT Key, Status FROM Validation WHERE Key='".$serial."'";`

Comment: This doesn't make any difference. If you use double quotes variables in strings are substituted with their value.

Comment: Thanks, now it returns something. But, no matter what key I POST, it returns invalid. The temp key is _2772_.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if at the last line you add this?

```
else echo 'Unknown method';
```

What may be happening is that $_POST and $_GET are not getting populated, this is a setting in php.ini, if I remember correctly (search for "superglobals" in the php docs).

**edit**: also, you have a very bad security risk there, google "sql injection". Basically the problem is that you could get any SQL directly into your database, and if the php user has enough permissions it could mean that anyone can, for example, delete all the data from your Validation table. You should at least do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Key, Status FROM Validation WHERE Key='".addslashes($serial)."'";
```

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string() instead of addslashes()

Answer (score 0):

It could be a typo but you are missing a closing parenthesis here:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 {
                              ^
```

And you might have turned off you error reporting, in which case you get a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing $serial:

```
echo $serial;
```

And is it what you typed in form?

Comment: Ok, but are you sure you chose the right database with a validation table? I know this is a stupid question, but that kind of things happen sometimes.

Comment: try echoing the mysql_real_escape_string($serial) value instead. Is it still the same?